# add DBCursor to memcached

Tags: java, mongodb, memcached

I have following codes:

```
 mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
 db = mongoClient.getDB("hcm");
 DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("segment_cell_details");
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("cell_x", cell_x).append("cell_y", cell_y);
 DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

Next, I want to add DBCursor in memcached :

```
c = new MemcachedClient(AddrUtil.getAddresses("localhost:11211"));
 c.add("Key", 3600, cursor);
```

Then, System prints out "Non-serializable object error"

So, how can I add the result of query to memcached ?

Comment: Iterate through the cursor's results and save them to memcached.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is an iterator that lazily loads the results.  You need to add the results not the iterator.  I recommend adding them as serialised JSON.

```
while (cursor.hasNext())
  c.add("key",3600,cursor.next().toString());
```